# PHP start program - PHPEd

Tags: php, command-line, protocols, phped

I'm developing a portal for (local) developers, and would like to make it possible to open PHP-files directly from the browser in PHPEd, by passing their name om the hard disk.

I've found two solutions, but couldn't get them to work:

- Solution 1: create a new protocol (phped_protocol) and use "`phped_protocol://[file]`" as URI
- Solution 2: execute a batch script that opens PHPEd

Could someone help me out with one of these solutions? I want to know how to open a PHP-file using PHPEd, via PHP/browser.

== Edit ==

**Solution 1**

test.reg

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phped_protocol] 
@="URL:phpedProtocol" 
"URL Protocol"="" 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phped_protocol\shell] 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phped_protocol\shell\open] 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\phped_protocol\shell\open\command] 
@="\"C:\\phped_protocol.bat\" \"%1\""
```

test.html

```
<a href="phped_protocol://[file]">Open file</a>
```

**Solution 2**

phped_protocol.bat

```
START "test" "C:\Program Files (x86)\NuSphere\PhpED\7.0\phped.exe"
EXIT
```

test.php

```
system('CMD /C C:\phped_protocol.bat');
```

Comment: please show the actual things you did for solution 1 and 2, and where you got stuck?

Comment: I've tried the above solutions, and several other things, like substitution system for exec, altering the command etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our current solution is a listener and a database. PHP inserts a record in the database. When the listeners finds it, it wil open the file.